# Complicated equation solving

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I want to find the maximum point or optimal value $y$ of Rx1[y_, a_, b_].

```
X1[y_, b_] := ((b/y - 1) + Sqrt[(b/y - 1)^2 + 2 b])/b;
Rx1[y_, a_, b_] := y Log[1 - a b X1[y, b] + (2 a b)/y];
```

I can prove that Rx1 has maximum for $y>0$ but it is difficult to get analytical solution. So I used `NSolve` and `FindRoot` in *Mathematica* making first derivative equals zero.

However, `NSolve` does not support when I calculate optimal $y$ for set of $a,b>0$ at once (e.g., {a,0.02,2,0.02} and {b,0.02,2,0.02}). Example:

```
DRx1[y_, a_, b_] := D[Rx1[y, a, b], {y, 1}];
yRx1[a_, b_] := 
      y /. NSolve[DRx1[y, a, b] == 0 && 0 <= y , y][[1]];
```

`FindRoot` does not provide correct answer for the same initial value (e.g., 0.2) for all sets, so I have to change initial point set by set, which is not desirable for me. Example:

```
yRx1[a_, b_] := y /. FindRoot[DRx1[y, a, b], {y, 0.2}]
```

Can someone suggest good technique?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `NMaximize`

```
yRx1[a_, b_] := y /. #2 & @@ NMaximize[{Rx1[y, a, b], y > 0}, y]
```

Example:

```
yRx1[1, 1.5]    
(*0.903322*)
```

Comment: Thanks !!! I am using 'yRx1[a_, b_] := y /. FindRoot[DRx1[y, a, b], {y, 0.2, 0.000001, 2}];' by initializing y-min and y-max. This works as well.